# Having troubles with jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am trying to get my data from action method and infact in Fiddler I get the json data but the grid doesn't show anything.

This is my .cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#customers').jqGrid({

            url: '/Home/Customers/',
            dataType: 'json',
            mType: 'POST',
            colNames: ['CustomerID', 'ContactName', 'ContactTitle', 'Country', 'CompanyName', 'Fax', 'Phone'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'CustomerID', index: 'CustomerID', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'ContactName', index: 'ContactName', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'ContactTitle', index: 'ContactTitle', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Country', index: 'Country', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'CompanyName', index: 'CompanyName', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Fax', index: 'Fax', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', align: 'left' },

            ],
            pager: jQuery('#customerPager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'CustomerID',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            imgpath: '',
            caption: 'My first grid'
        });

    });
</script>
```

In _Layout.cshtml, I have reference to scripts and I they all load properly:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/ui.multiselect.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/grid.locale-en.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is my Home controller's action method:

```
public JsonResult Customers(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows )
        {
            NorthwindEntities entities = new NorthwindEntities();
            int pageIndex = page - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            int totalRecords = entities.Customers.Count();
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling( (float)totalRecords / pageSize);
            var customers = entities.Customers.OrderBy(k => k.CustomerID).Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = (from customer in customers 
                            select new {
                                    i = customer.CustomerID,
                                    cell = new string[]{customer.CustomerID, customer.ContactName,
                                            customer.ContactTitle, customer.Country, customer.CompanyName,
                                            customer.Fax,
                                            customer.Phone
                                    }
                            }).ToArray()
            };

            return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main error is that you use **wrong case** in the jqGrid option names (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). The `dataType: 'json'` must be `datatype: 'json'`, the `mType: 'POST'` must be `mtype: 'POST'`. Moreover you use very old template for your solution which originate from [the Phil Haack demo](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx). One can see that at least from the bug in the controller action: you use `i = customer.CustomerID` instead of `id = customer.CustomerID`.

Additionally you should include `jquery-ui-1.8.16.min.js` instead of `jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js` if you use `jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css`. I recommend you to use jQuery 1.6.2. The xxx-vsdoc.js file you can download from [the Microsoft page](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx#jQuery_Releases_on_the_CDN_0). Be careful with jQuery 1.6.3 some small bug fixes in jqGrid can be required (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358995/jquery-1-6-3-checkboxes-issue-in-inline-edit-in-jqgrid/7359390#7359390) an example).

I recomend you to download my [VS2010 demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemoVS2010.zip) or [VS2008 demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jqGridDemo.zip) which I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500805/asp-net-mvc-2-0-implementation-of-searching-in-jqgrid/5501644#5501644). The demo is based on the Phil Haack demo, but it's modified so that it support error reporting, searching or toolbar filtering and has some small, but very useful CSS fixes which you need to eliminate small conflicts between the standard ASP.NET MVC CSS and jqGrid CSS.

Comment: :D you are awesome with sharp eyes. datatype and mtype did the trick!. Still I will download your solution and see what goodies I can found in it. Thanks anyways Oleg. I wish I could give you few votes more.

Comment: @Anthony: You are welcome! The main advantage of the voting is that other people could find the answer better, because the answers high voted are on top on the searching results. So I'm glad that I could help you. If you would find any other answers which gives you new or interesting information just use your voting rights for the answers. It will help other people to find the information.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that I will find so for this question. I've studied your code thorougly and I must be say you have written it beautifully. Absolutely beautiful!