# No row added when using jqGrid json format

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I just start using jqgrid, but when I try the most simple example (loading JSON data), it is not working (no row added on tbody)

I have load these file in head section

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://192.168.3.9/wavinet2-permana/application/themes/default/css/jqueryui/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.css">

<script src="http://192.168.3.9/wavinet2-permana/application/themes/default/js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://192.168.3.9/wavinet2-permana/application/themes/default/js/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/wavinet2-permana/application/assets/css/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid.css">

<script src="/wavinet2-permana/application/assets/js/jqgrid/i18n/grid.locale-id.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/wavinet2-permana/application/assets/js/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And I have the javascript to load and config jqgrid

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#list2').jqGrid({
url: SITE_URL+'/account/test/jqgrid_ajax',
dataType: 'json',
mtype: 'GET',
colNames: ['Username', 'Nama Person'],
colModel: [
{name:'username', index: 'username', width:200, key:true},
{name:'nama_person', index: 'nama_person', width:200}
],
rowNum: 10,
rowList: [10, 20, 30],
pager: '#pager2',
sortname: 'username',
sortorder: 'ASC',
caption: 'Account Example',
viewrecords: true,
jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}
});
$('#list2').jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',{edit:false,add:false,del:false}); 
</script>
```

body

```
<table id="list2" width="100%"></table>
<div id="pager2"></div>
```

JSON response

```
{
   "page":"1",
   "total":"2",
   "records":"13",
   "rows":[
      {
         "id":"Oke1",
         "cell":[
            "Oke1",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke2",
         "cell":[
            "Oke2",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke3",
         "cell":[
            "Oke3",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke4",
         "cell":[
            "Oke4",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke5",
         "cell":[
            "Oke5",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke6",
         "cell":[
            "Oke6",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke7",
         "cell":[
            "Oke7",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke8",
         "cell":[
            "Oke8",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke9",
         "cell":[
            "Oke9",
            "Deh"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":"Oke10",
         "cell":[
            "Oke10",
            "Deh"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I try to open in Firefox Windows, Firefox Ubuntu, and Internet Explorer 8, it returns the same result. The grid is rendered but there are no data on tbody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two small errors in your code:

- you should use `datatype: 'json'` instead of `dataType: 'json'` which you probably know from [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
- you should remove `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false}` parameter.

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Permana.htm).

I recommend you additionally to use jQuery 1.6.2 instead of jQuery 1.4.4 which is now already "retro" version. With the version 1.6.3 you should be a little more sensible (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358995/jquery-1-6-3-checkboxes-issue-in-inline-edit-in-jqgrid/7359390#7359390)). In the same way jQuery UI 1.8.8 is also an old version. I recommend you to use jQuery UI 1.8.16.

Comment: thanks for creating the demo page. but, what is multiCol.js ? because I can't find this file on jqgrid that I download

Comment: @Permana: This was cut & paste error. You can use just the standard `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead. I fixed the demo now. At the time I just worked on some suggestions to change jqGrid to allow support multiple column headers (groups of the headers) like [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridHeadersWithFirstRow4.htm) described in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341339/jqgrid-column-group/7351638#7351638). I just forget to change the name of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`.