# jqgrid not processing checkbox values

Tags: jqgrid, checkbox

I am using jqGrid 4.1.2 and checkboxes are not updating as I navigate the input form.  For example if I check a checkbox and submit form the change is recorded in the database, but the checkbox tick is not displayed if I reload the form.

```
{name:'entireTooth',width:50, editable:true, hidden:true, edittype:'checkbox',formatter: 'checkbox', editoptions:{value:'Yes:No'}, editrules:{edithidden:true}}
```

Produces the checkbox in the form:

http://screencast.com/t/jFJeoJWL

Firebug shows the HTML created as this:

```
<input id="entireTooth" class="FormElement" type="checkbox" value="Yes" offval="No" name="entireTooth" role="checkbox">
```

jqGrid records changes to the database correctly, it just fails to update the checkbox to the database value when the form is loaded.

Thanks for any suggestions and help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358995/jquery-1-6-3-checkboxes-issue-in-inline-edit-in-jqgrid/7359390#7359390) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/checkboxes-in-inline-editing-cant-be-unchecked-in-jquery-1-6-3-and-1-6-4/#p24613). The problem is already fixed in jqGrid 4.2.0. So you should just update jqGrid which you use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Oleg, I downloaded the latest version and the files have been reorganised and conflict with other code in the project so I will have to stick with 4.1.2 and find another solution.

Comment: @Martyn Walker: If you have to use jqGrid 4.1.2 you can just use jQuery in the version <= 1.6.2